# Enable accessibility mode in widget as default

Tags: functions, widgets, accessibility

Guys how can I Enable widget accessibility mode as a default for all users, I thought about update_user_meta in wp_user-settings but I was not successful.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

All enabling Accessibility Mode does is add a class to the admin body. The styles and script behaviour change based on that class. So if you want to make accessibility mode the default, you can add that same class if the user hasn't set accessibility mode on or off:

```
add_filter( 
    'admin_body_class', 
    function( $classes ) {
        $widgets_access = get_user_setting( 'widgets_access' );

        if ( empty( $widgets_access ) ) {
            $classes = $classes . ' widgets_access';
        }

        return $classes;
    }
);
```